# Getting Correct Value from select form in Laravel collective

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravelcollective

I just started to use Laravel Collective. However, I encounter a problem when I try to extract the value from the Select Form.

```
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST','action'=>['ExpenseController@store'],'files' =>false], array('enctype'=>'multipart/form-data','id'=>'customer_contact','class' => 'form-validate1')) !!}
      {{ Form::select('account_categories', $account_name,null, array("class"=>"dropdown-toggle form-control",'placeholder'=>'Please select ...')) }}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

And it will look like this
[image]

But when I try to get the value from this select form via $request and return back to the Laravel, it output number instead of string value selected by user like this:

```
"account_categories":"5"
```

How can I get the string value selected by users from this SELECTBOX FORM ?

Comment: Thats the KEY of the row containing the TEXT that the user sees i.e. the `value=` attribute

Comment: Remember its just a framework, it does nto change the way HTML works

Comment: @RiggsFolly How can I get the TEXT instead of the KEY of the row? Or I have to manually translate that key back to the string again?

Comment: You normally would use the key to get the correct data from the database

Comment: @RiggsFolly, oh, I see what you mean by that. Thx.